# Need a script that creates folders in Google Drive from data entered in sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to write a google app script that would create a folder in my Google Drive every time I enter a new submission to the "A" column in my google sheet. Currently all of the scripts that I have found or attempted to write haven't worked. Any help would greatly be appreciate!

```
function createAndHyperlink() {
var ss, sh, parent, r, v, thisCell, folder
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
sh = ss.getSheetByName('Projects')
parent = DriveApp.getFolderById('Projects');
r = sh.getRange('A1:A')
v = r.getValues()
for (var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i++) {
    thisCell = sh.getRange(i + 1, 1)
    if (v[i][0] && !thisCell.getFormula()) {
        folder = parent.createFolder(v[i][0]);
        thisCell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + folder.getUrl() + '"; "' + v[i][0] + '")');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Please post your code, and also adding google-app-script tag to get better attention. But first you need to show us some code

Comment: try freelancer dot com

Answer (score 0):

> ... create a folder in my Google Drive every time I enter a new submission to the "A" column in my google sheet.

If you were looking for an automation where as soon as you enter something in Column A, the script was to create a folder then unfortunately that wouldn't be possible as the "trigger" that you'd then require would be the `onEdit` one which -

> ... cannot access [services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services) that require [authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization).

Please refer to [Simple Triggers > Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions).

However, the aforementioned code that you've provided works perfectly well when being used appropriately; here's the same code with a minor tweak -

```
function createAndHyperlink() {
  var ss, sh, parent, r, v, thisCell, folder
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  parent = DriveApp.getFolderById('18SMDKdmc4qk1SNxtQHvSdX1LFyn_lq9S'); // enter the folder ID and not the folder name (refer image below)
  r = sh.getRange('A1:A')
  v = r.getValues()
  for (var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i++) {
    thisCell = sh.getRange(i + 1, 1)
    if (v[i][0] && !thisCell.getFormula()) {
      folder = parent.createFolder(v[i][0]);
      thisCell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + folder.getUrl() + '"; "' + v[i][0] + '")');
    }
  }
}
```

[image: folder id]

*This* will accordingly create new folders within the parent folder and hyperlink the values from Column A with their respective, destination folders.

Hope this helps.